# table view is not reloading when calling function reloaddata() inside getCArrayList method

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift4, xcode9

```
func getCArrayList(id:String, array:[NSDictionary] ){

    videolist = NSMutableArray()
    videoId = NSMutableArray()
    image = NSMutableArray()

    for i in 0 ..< array.count
    {
        let adict:NSDictionary = array[i] as! NSDictionary

        let bdict:NSDictionary = adict.object(forKey: "snippet") as! NSDictionary
        let cdict:NSDictionary = bdict.object(forKey: "resourceId") as! NSDictionary
        let ddict:NSDictionary = bdict.object(forKey: "thumbnails") as! NSDictionary
        let edict:NSDictionary = ddict.object(forKey: "medium") as! NSDictionary

        self.videolist.add(bdict.object(forKey: "title") as! String)
        self.videoId.add(cdict.object(forKey: "videoId") as! String)
        self.image.add(edict.object(forKey: "url") as! String)

        if videoId[i] as! String == id {
            self.videolist.remove(i)
            self.videoId.remove(i)
            self.image.remove(i)
        }

    }

    self.videotable.reloadData()

}

//calling the fuction:
 getCArrayList(id: videoid, array: didselectarray)
```

when calling this function getCArrayList ,tableview is not reloading
the fuction is being called in tableview method didselectrowatindexpath()
where am i doint wrong? any help is appreciated....

Comment: this method is called in main thread?

Comment: Not related to this question, but stop force unwrapping values please.

Comment: @ReinierMelian DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.videotable.reloadData()
            }                         tried this but no change

Comment: check array.count....it should be grater than zero.....to reload data in table view

Comment: what is the tableView array ????

Comment: I think your parse logic gives empty array ,  check array content with print before reload

Comment: parsing is correct and arrays have conent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following :

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
     self.videotable.reloadData()
}
```

Hope it may help.

Comment: still no change table view is not reloading

Comment: Your tableview delegate & datasource method are called or not?

Comment: yes i have defined those fuctions and i am calling GetCArrayList method inside tableview didselectrow()

Comment: when code runs it shows items in tableview.and when user clicks on a cell it is supposed to show different data, thats why i am calling realoaddata() method

Comment: Can you show your code for numberOfRowsInSection & cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return videolist.count
    }

Comment: Check if your videolist.count is greater than 0. And can you show your code for cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: it is greater than 0.the code for cell for row index path exceeds the limits thats why i am unable to post it. now i have a new error after changing the if condition to this in the getCArrayList function : if videoId[i] as! String != id{
                self.videolist.add(bdict.object(forKey: "title") as! String)
                self.videoId.add(cdict.object(forKey: "videoId") as! String)
                self.image.add(edict.object(forKey: "url") as! String)        when executing this function i get ns exception: libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException